# Python PIL ImageDraw.polygon not drawing the polygon if it is a line or a point

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

As can be seen in the examples below, if a polygon is a line or a point it is not drawn. I do not think that this is the desired behaviour. In theory a line is also a polygon right?

From the [docs of PIL](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.polygon):

> **ImageDraw.polygon(xy, fill=None, outline=None)**
>
> Draws a polygon.
>
> The polygon outline consists of straight lines between the given coordinates, plus a straight  line between the last and the first coordinate.
>
> ...

To me this suggests that the `.polygon` method works by drawing lines between points, however, as seen in example #2 it definitely does not.

Could anybody tell me why this is the case? Could someone also tell me how I can make it so that, even if the polygon is a line or point, it is still drawn?

#1 Point as polygon:

```py
Python 3.7.6 (v3.7.6:43364a7ae0, Dec 18 2019, 14:18:50) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
>>> import numpy as np
>>> img = Image.new('L', (5, 5), 0)
>>> ImageDraw.Draw(img).polygon([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], outline=1, fill=1)
>>> np.array(img)
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```

#2 Line as polygon:

```py
>>> img = Image.new('L', (5, 5), 0)
>>> ImageDraw.Draw(img).polygon([1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1], outline=1, fill=1)
>>> np.array(img)
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```

#3 Squire as polygon:

```py
>>> img = Image.new('L', (5, 5), 0)
>>> ImageDraw.Draw(img).polygon([1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2], outline=1, fill=1)
>>> np.array(img)
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```

Edit:
I googled a bit for the definition of a polygon;

> In geometry, a polygon can be defined as a flat or plane, two-dimensional closed shape with straight sides.

[source](https://www.splashlearn.com/math-vocabulary/geometry/polygon)

> A plane figure with at least three straight sides and angles, and typically five or more.

[source](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/polygon)

So a new question arises; are angles of 0 degrees also counted as angles in geometry? According to [this source](https://www.sparknotes.com/math/geometry1/constructions/section1/#:%7E:text=An%20angle%20with%20a%20measure,lie%20in%20the%20same%20line.) it is:

> Zero Angles
>
> An angle with a measure of zero degrees is called a zero
> angle. If this is hard to visualize, consider two rays that form some
> angle greater than zero degrees, like the rays in the . Then picture
> one of the rays rotating toward the other ray until they both lie in
> the same line. The angle they create has been shrunk from its original
> measure to zero degrees. The angle that is now formed has a measure of
> zero degrees.

Answer (score 1):

While this does not explain the behaviour of the `.polygon` method, I have found a workaround.

By combining `.polygon` with <s>`.point`</s> `.line` you will get the desired result. (See edit below on why to use `.line` over `.point`)

#1 Point

```py
Python 3.7.6 (v3.7.6:43364a7ae0, Dec 18 2019, 14:18:50) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
>>> import numpy as np
>>> img = Image.new('L', (5, 5), 0)
>>> ImageDraw.Draw(img).polygon([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], outline=1, fill=1)
>>> ImageDraw.Draw(img).line([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], fill=1)
>>> np.array(img)
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```

#2 Line

```py
>>> img = Image.new('L', (5, 5), 0)
>>> ImageDraw.Draw(img).polygon([1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1], outline=1, fill=1)
>>> ImageDraw.Draw(img).line([1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1], fill=1)
>>> np.array(img)
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```

#3 Rectangle

```py
>>> img = Image.new('L', (5, 5), 0)
>>> ImageDraw.Draw(img).polygon([1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2], outline=1, fill=1)
>>> ImageDraw.Draw(img).line([1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2], fill=1)
>>> np.array(img)
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```

**EDIT**:
To make this also work for longer lines (see below) `.line` has to be used instead of `.point`.

With `.point`

```py
>>> img = Image.new('L', (5, 5), 0)
>>> ImageDraw.Draw(img).polygon([1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1], outline=1, fill=1)
>>> ImageDraw.Draw(img).point([1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1], fill=1)
>>> np.array(img)
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```

With `.line`

```py
>>> img = Image.new('L', (5, 5), 0)
>>> ImageDraw.Draw(img).polygon([1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1], outline=1, fill=1)
>>> ImageDraw.Draw(img).line([1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1], fill=1)
>>> np.array(img)
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that since this was originally posted, PIL has been updated such that `ImageDraw.Draw.polygon()` will now fill in pixels for a point or a line.  I did not dig deeply into the change logs to track down when this may have been fixed, as `ImageDraw.Draw.polygon()` calls into `Image.core.draw.draw_polygon()`, which is a C module and its interface is not publicly documented.

I'm running Python 3.11.1 with PIL version 9.4.0

**Example 1 - Point:**

```
>>> from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
>>> import numpy as np
>>> imgP = Image.new('L', (5,5), 0)
>>> ImageDraw.Draw(imgP).polygon([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], outline=1, fill=1)
>>> np.array(imgP)
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```

**Example 2 - Line:**

```
>>> from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
>>> import numpy as np
>>> imgL = Image.new('L', (5, 5), 0) 
>>> ImageDraw.Draw(imgL).polygon([1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1], outline=1, fill=1)  
>>> np.array(imgL)
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```